# ImportError: No module named <module name> module inside folder

Tags: python, import

I'm importing files from the following folder inside a python code:

```
Mask_RCNN
  -mrcnn
    -config.py
    -model.py
    -__init__.py
    -utils.py
    -visualize.py
```

I'm using the following imports:

These work ok:
    from Mask_RCNN.mrcnn.config import Config
    from Mask_RCNN. mrcnn import utils

These give me error:

```
from Mask_RCNN.mrcnn import visualize
import mrcnn.model as modellib
```

Error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'mrcnn'
```

How to import these properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an error for the 2nd import, where you omit `Mask_RCNN` from the package name.

Try changing the lines to:

```
from Mask_RCNN.mrcnn import visualize
import Mask_RCNN.mrcnn.model as modellib
```

Comment: in colab.research.google.com, tf=2.5.0, keras=2.4.3. `from Mask_RCNN.mrcnn import utils` works but `import Mask_RCNN.mrcnn.model as modellib` throw the error "Requires TensorFlow 1.3+ and Keras 2.0.8+.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mrcnn'" any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use this line before importing the libraries

```
sys.path.append("Mask_RCNN/")
```